# is it possible to have a background color and a background image at the same time on a pseudo element in css

Tags: css, html

I have a template i need to override.My div is centered in the middle and as my design uses a fullwidth ribbon i used :before and :after to create the effect.it worked now on top of that ribbon i need to have an image displayed on top of it.it works for the main div but for the pseudo elements i cant get it to work.

```
.backbox:before
{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 5000px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: gray;
    background-image:url(/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/buildings.png) ;
    background-position:bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    top:0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    left: -4985px;
    z-index: 5;
}
.backbox:after
{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 5000px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: gray;
    background-image:url(/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/buildings.png) ;
    background-position:bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    position: absolute;
    right: -4985px;
    z-index:5;
}
```

Edit:
As you requested here is an image of what the web page should actually look like
[image]

Comment: I suspect we need a brief demo with the actual images...but those width and left & right values scare me. An image of what this is supposed to look like would be useful too.

Comment: I don't think your CSS is wrong. Background colors and images work on pseudo elements at the same time, just fine. Make sure your image paths are correct, they look odd to me. I really hope you're not putting CSS where that path tells me it is. Also, I think I should mention it's probably a bad idea to pull images from the uploads folder of WordPress anyway. If it's for the theme it should go in the theme folder.

Comment: @Dustin ...i edited my post to add an image of what the website should look like.the ribbon i am talking about is in the middle.if you zoom in enough you should be able to see some buildings on the gray background....and yes you are right about the upload folder i ll change that ASAP

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use z-index for this? 
So put make a div surrounding both the ribbon and the image you want to put on top of it. Then make the ribbon a z-index: 1; and the image and z-index: 2;

Comment: yeah i did that one already.ill explain the page is centered  in the middle and i cant override it as wordpress doesnt allow me to put code before the div main so i am stuck with a centered design.so in order to get a full width ribbon effect i used :before and :after pseudo elements.iam able to put both a background color and a background image in the div that is centered now i should be able to put the same image on the :before and :after to create the effect of a full ribbon with an image...check the image i added to get an idea of what i am talking about.Thanks